# The step clause of this for-loop is not of the expected form

Tags: c++, c++11, misra

```
for(auto Itr = PropVal.value.int32Values.begin();
        Itr != PropVal.value.int32Values.end();
        Itr++) // Non-compliant according to MISRA
```

> The step clause of this for-loop is not of the expected form. It must be an expression whose only persistent side effect is to modify the loop counter.  The loop counter has been identified as <cs.ast [cc:variable] Itr>. A for loop shall be well-formed.

what is the alternative way instead of use of begin() and end()?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you are asking. The loop uses iterators instead of indices, did you mean that?

Comment: What compiler generates this error?

Comment: `++Itr` instead of `Itr++`?

Comment: Especially when using classes to iterate, I'd recommond using `++Itr` instead of `Itr++`. The latter does conceptually more work. The message you got is somewhat odd, though.

Comment: Hmmm, MISRA.  Does this help? - see Page 297 of this document
https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/adaptive/17-10/AUTOSAR_RS_CPP14Guidelines.pdf

Comment: I suspect the rationale is that you should be using `cbegin` and `cend` for the iterator, so there is a guarantee that the iterator will be const and the step clause can not possibly modify the range.  A "move to next iteration" step could possibly mutate the range if it is not constant and implemented badly.

Comment: I don't think MISRA-C++ allows C++11. Because going for MISRA compliance and C++11 at the same time is kind of like putting on a safety helmet then go throwing yourself under a bus. If you write mission critical software, then simply _don't_ use C++11 or later: that's plain quackery.

Comment: In this case I would use a ranged based for loop